# csv to html table possible?

Tags: python, html, csv, html-table

i have a csv file full of calendar information (calendar-data.csv)
i need to take it and publish it to a web page (or generate the html for it)

what i would like is to have the dates run across the table (in the Start column) then have the employee names run down the left side. in each date box the corresponding task should be filled in

so it would look like:

```
             03/15/2019    03/16/2019

employee1      task            task 
                               task

employee2      task
               task
```

this code gives me the html but its all one blob on the webpage :

```
import csv
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
  print "Usage: ./csv-html.py <your CSV file> <your HTML File.html>"
  print
  print
  exit(0)

# Open the CSV file for reading
reader = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1]))

# Create the HTML file
f_html = open(sys.argv[2],"w");
f_html.write('<title><Work Flow></title>')

for row in reader: # Read a single row from the CSV file
  f_html.write('<tr>');# Create a new row in the table
  for column in row: # For each column..
    f_html.write('<td>' + column + '</td>');
  f_html.write('</tr>')


f_html.write('</table>')
```

is this possible in python or should i look elsewhere?

thanks

### Edit:

right now the html out put looks like this:

```
employee1 03/15/2019    tasks
employee1  03/15/2019   tasks
employee2  03/15/2019   tasks
employee2  03/16/2019   tasks
```

however i would like it to look like this:

```
            03/15/2019           03/16/2019            03/17/2019

employee1      tasks               tasks
employee2      task                tasks
employee3                                                tasks
```

### Edit 2

use pivot to move around date:

```
data = data.pivot(index='Employee', columns = 'Start', values='Task').reset_index()
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the csv file? I'd like to show an example for my solution.

Comment: @GrantWilliams: 
`Employee Start Task
John smith 2019-03-04 "6 prog xfers//69 Door seals, 8 Door Seal verifications 14:30 to 16:30 at office
Lunch 17:00 to 18:00 at Lunch
continuation from this morning inspections 18:30 to 20:00 at office"
John smith 2019-03-05 "online betting 12:00 to 14:30 at 1300
10 r/c's, 2 board brks, 1 pci card change 14:30 to 18:00 at office
Lunch 18:00 to 19:00 at Lunch
(cxl'd reschedule for 3/6) 2 board seals 19:30 to 20:30 at office"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read in the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame using [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and then convert to html using [pandas.to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)

For a CSV File "input.csv"

```
employee_name, 03/15/2019,03/16/2019
employee1, task1,task2 
employee2, task3, task4
```

We can read the CSV file as a DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("input.csv", index_col="employee_name")
```

where df is

```
               03/15/2019 03/16/2019
employee_name
employee1           task1     task2
employee2           task3      task4
```

Then we can convert the DataFrame to an HTML table with

```
df.to_html("input.html")
```

And the output of the HTML file "intput.html" will be

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>03/15/2019</th>
      <th>03/16/2019</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>employee_name</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>employee1</th>
      <td>task1</td>
      <td>task2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>employee2</th>
      <td>task3</td>
      <td>task4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: awesome this helps a lot. or at least is pointing me in the right direction. need to figure out how to put the dates as the header row with the tasks filled in under it. thanks for the help!

Comment: ok so this really did help a lot! even figure out how to get the line breaks in for the multi tasks days.

however would you know how to have it so the date runs across the top? almost like a calendar look to it?  would that be more of a css thing?

Comment: @stcoyle I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that. Could you post an example of the output you want in your original question?

Comment: sure thing. i hope the edit makes sense.  Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: i figured it out :) needed to use pivot: 

data = data.pivot(index='Employee', columns = 'Start', values='Task').reset_index()